# Create a module and connect API

Tags: 7, javascript

Hello I am new to drupal 7, I want to create an module where I use and connect an API to my website. Any help from where to start?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) We don't locate tutorials/documentation here, Google is your friend for that. We just answer small, narrowly scoped, specific questions about practical problems that are faced while building Drupal sites. There's a lot more info in the [help],  that will help to clear up what kinds of questions should be asked here. If you have such a question, please ask it separately. Many thanks